# Is there a convention for Javadoc linking class member variables to UI elements

Tags: java, javadoc

In a large web application I have been working on in Java, various user inputs from the UI form elements are stored in class structures. Variable names are typically created to reflect the data stored in them, but over time and changes it may no longer be clear which data element stores data from which UI form element.

Is there a convention for using Javadoc to track the mappings between class data members and UI elements?

I've started out by saying that for instance variable lastName is set from the form element with the label myworkflow.step1.lastname(referring to the properties file that contains the UI element labels).

Is this a good approach or is there a more formalised convention on doing this?